# Limit SQL by the sum of the row's value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I'm kind of stumped here, I have a table setup like this

```
+-----------+------+
| Timestamp | Size |
+-----------+------+
|   1-1-13  + 10.3 +
+-----------+------+
|   1-3-13  +  6.7 +
+-----------+------+
|   1-5-13  +  3.0 +
+-----------+------+
|   1-9-13  + 11.4 +
+-----------+------+
```

And I'm wondering if there's any way to run a query like this

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT BY (SUM(size) <= 20.0);`

This should grab the first three rows, because the sum of the size in of the first 3 rows is 20. However, it might not always be 3 rows that equal 20. Sometimes the first row might have a value of 20, and in that case, it should only grab the first one.

I'm already aware that this it's possible to quickly calculate the sum in PHP after the query is run, but I'm trying to accomplish this with just MySQL.

Comment: So you want a running total?

Comment: In ANSI SQL you select rows of some table ( relation ) based on criteria which are matched for EVERY SINGLE ROW of output. In your example, criteria changes with every new row. Not sure, but I think it will require PL/SQL function. Note how ORDER works - depending on use of subquery, you will get different results, depending if you want output to be sorted, or input which is to be matched under your condition, and ORDER is not supposed to be used like that. LIMIT ( or OFFSET ) is probably supposed to be used for simple limit number of rows on output, not by expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to add a running total, and limit based on that, the following should work:

```
SET @runtot:=0;
 SELECT 
    q1.t,
    q1.s,
    (@runtot := @runtot + q1.s) AS rt
 FROM 
    (SELECT Date AS t,
     SIZE AS s
     FROM  Table1
     ORDER  BY Date
     ) AS q1
WHERE @runtot + q1.s <= 20
```

Edit:  Demo here - [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76f81/1/0)

Comment: Turns out after a little bit of research, you're indeed correct. Calculating a running total performs better than joining. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: What will happen if there are only items with `size` > 20? If the query will produce no results, can you suggest how to change the query so that it fetches at least `20` total size, and stops fetching more rows as soon as the total is greater or equal to `20`?

Answer (score 7):

```
 SELECT * FROM ints ORDER BY i;
 +---+
 | i |
 +---+
 | 0 |
 | 1 |
 | 2 |
 | 3 |
 | 4 |
 | 5 |
 | 6 |
 | 7 |
 | 8 |
 | 9 |
 +---+

 SELECT x.* ,SUM(y.i) FROM ints x JOIN ints y ON y.i <= x.i GROUP BY x.i;
 +---+----------+
 | i | SUM(y.i) |
 +---+----------+
 | 0 |        0 |
 | 1 |        1 |
 | 2 |        3 |
 | 3 |        6 |
 | 4 |       10 |
 | 5 |       15 |
 | 6 |       21 |
 | 7 |       28 |
 | 8 |       36 |
 | 9 |       45 |
 +---+----------+

 SELECT x.* ,SUM(y.i) FROM ints x JOIN ints y ON y.i <= x.i GROUP BY x.i HAVING SUM(y.i) <= 20;
 +---+----------+
 | i | SUM(y.i) |
 +---+----------+
 | 0 |        0 |
 | 1 |        1 |
 | 2 |        3 |
 | 3 |        6 |
 | 4 |       10 |
 | 5 |       15 |
 +---+----------+
```

Comment: I was trying to resolve the problem by subquery, join is so better and readable. +1

Comment: Wow, great answer. Is there any performance issues doing this?

Comment: running total by variable saves the overhead of a self JOIN.

Comment: So your saying your running total solution is the better solution performance wise?

Comment: I believe so, definitely is in MSSQL, can't confirm performance increase in MySQL

Comment: @iGARET Yes. If performance seems sluggish, consider Goat_CO's solution instead.

Comment: +1 and wish it could be more - absolutely brilliant query and great explanation!

Comment: :-) Steady! While I appreciate the enthusiasm, let's not overdo it, what.

Answer (score 1):

Using *window functions* (in MySQL 8.0+ and MariaDB 10.2+):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT t.*, SUM(size) OVER (
    PARTITION by NULL
    ORDER BY t.Timestamp
    RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) as csum
  FROM MyTable t
  ORDER BY t.Timestamp
) x
WHERE csum <= 20;
```

Or shorter:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT t.*, SUM(size) OVER (ORDER BY t.Timestamp) as csum
  FROM MyTable t
  ORDER BY t.Timestamp
) x
WHERE csum <= 20;
```

[***Demo on db-fiddle.com***](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qjP3h3wA9CRPo8jovHEtcV/0)