# MySQL query to get first 10 in total `qty`

Tags: mysql, sql

So, my table is :

| *uid | code | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CODE2200 | 5 |
| 2 | CODE2205 | 6 |
| 3 | CODE0002 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I want to fetch only first maximum of 10 from qty.

The result i want is :

| *uid | code | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CODE2200 | 5 |
| 2 | CODE2205 | 6 |

What i know is, `limit` is for counting the first 'n' row, so it cant be used here.

I'm trying to use `WHERE SUM(qty) <= 10` also not work.

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version? Does the rows must be selected in some definite order (by uid, by code, something else) until cumulative sum reaches needed limit?

Comment: *The result i want is* ?? the cumulative sum for these rows is 11 which is over needed 10... why?

Comment: aggregate functions are not work at WHERE clause.  Please explain your logic briefly.

Comment: This might be the same question with answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109602/limit-sql-by-the-sum-of-the-rows-value

Answer (score 0):

You can use *window* function :

```
select uid, code, qty
from (select t.*, sum(qty) over(order by uid) as qtysum
      from t
     ) t
where qtysum <= 10;
```

Comment: Close. That returns the first row only, but the OP seems to want as many rows as necessary to cover the required quantity. And this query is based on the UID order. This is likely to be desired, but the OP has failed so far to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative sum.  To get the first row that *exceeds* 10:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(qty) over (order by uid) as running_qty
      from t
     ) t
where running_qty - qty < 10;
```

If you wanted the first row that hits the threshold of 10:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(qty) over (order by uid) as running_qty
      from t
     ) t
where running_qty - qty < 10 and
      qty >= 10;
```